# Variable is never assigned to, and will always have the default value null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make my elements referenced in Unity by making private variables using Serializable Fields and then using a {get {return }} underneath in order to access it. I'm a complete beginner at C# and Unity so I'd appreciate a simple explanation. Every one of these Serializable Fields has this same error and doesn't appear in my Unity inspector.

```
    public struct UIElements
    {
        [SerializeField] RectTransform answerContentArea;
        public RectTransform AnswerContentArea { get { return answerContentArea; } }

        [SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI questionInfoTextObject;
        public TextMeshProUGUI QuestionInfoTextObject { get { return questionInfoTextObject; } }

        [SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI scoreText;
        public TextMeshProUGUI ScoreText { get { return scoreText; } }

        [Space]

        [SerializeField] Image resolutionBG;
        public Image ResolutionBG { get { return resolutionBG; } }

        [SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI resolutionStateInfoText;
        public TextMeshProUGUI ResolutionStateInfoText { get { return resolutionStateInfoText; } }

        [SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI resolutionScoreText;
        public TextMeshProUGUI ResolutionScoreText { get { return resolutionScoreText; } }

        [Space]

        [SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI highScoreText;
        public TextMeshProUGUI HighScoreText { get { return highScoreText; } }

        [SerializeField] CanvasGroup mainCanvasGroup;
        public CanvasGroup MainCanvasGroup { get { return mainCanvasGroup; } }

        [SerializeField] RectTransform finishUIElements;
        public RectTransform FinishUIElements { get { return finishUIElements; } }
    }
```

Comment: this is normal. You can set them to null and it will shut up, or empty values..

Comment: @BugFinder I tried setting them to null and I was given an error of "UIElements" cannot have instance property or field initialisers in structs.

Comment: ah cos its a struct not a class.. if its a class you would..

Comment: @BugFinder Ah don't worry about it mate, I just fixed it. I had to put [Serializable()] before the struct so that Unity would recognise that I was using it. Thanks for the help anyway :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mark the struct as `Serializable` in order to show it in the Unity Inspector, like so:

```
[Serializable]
public struct UIElements
{
// ...
}
```

As for the warning, it is normal, so you can ignore it.
Just make sure to set those respective values in the inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Unity provides [serialization system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html) for MonoBehaviour's fields which you can use to set fields links in editor and later use it from code.

In you case you need to make `UIElements` as class which inherits from `MonoBehaviour`, attach it to some GameObject at scene and set up needed links - after this you can use links for objects in scene.

Answer (score 0):

All of your fields seem to be defined as [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties). Someone correct me if I'm wrong but in order to display property in the inspector you have to "create" your own inspector because Unity cannot safely serialize/deserialize properties since getters and setters can have different effects based on what code they encapsulate.

I hope this [post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/custom-inspector-how-do-you-show-all-the-properties-of-a-component.511477/) sheds more light for you.

#### Edit

[This](https://forum.unity.com/threads/exposing-properties-in-the-inspector.471363/) might also be useful

Comment: There are properties to access the private fields that are displayed in Inspector.

Comment: It would improve your answer if you included the information in the links in the answer itself in case the post gets edited/removed or the thread goes missing.

Comment: All shown properties are using SerializeField backing fields ... So there is no issue with the Inspector at all.